# ScrollView dismisses Keyboard when content is added/content size changes

Tags: react-native

I am using a `ScrollView` with the properties `keyboardDismissMode='none'` and `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'`, which works as intended as I can tap elements and scroll the view without dismissing the Keyboard.

But as soon as I add new content to the scroll view the keyboard is dismissed.

How can I avoid this?

I am using react-native `0.40.0`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you shouldn't update any parent view of the scrollview as that will actually dismiss the keyboard...